# Can I add a bounty to post where I've already accepted an answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Yesterday, I received [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149945/709443) to a jQuery question I had, and it's so good I think it deserves more than the four upvotes it got due to the question being low traffic, so I thought I'd award it a bounty.

However, there doesn't seem to be an option for that - is that because I've accepted an answer or because it's less than two days old?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because it's less than 2 days old. Once it's 48 hours old, then you may place a bounty on it. There's an option to declare that the bounty is to reward an existing answer, as shown below,

[image]

Then you can wait 7 days and bask in glory as your question and/or the chosen answer collect upvotes (hopefully). After 7 days, there is a 24 hour grace period in which you can select which answer to award the bounty to. **Don't miss that deadline**, otherwise *half* of the bounty automatically goes to the highest upvoted answer (with a minimum score of two) that was posted after the bounty started.

You can get the full gory details at [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @theB I try, I try ;)

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Everything you need to know about bountys.

Your answer in this case is that, yes, after the question is 2 days old, you can set and eventually award a bounty to that answer.